# im creating a map where in the first activity is permission to open location then the next activity is opening the map

Tags: android, android-manifest

I think the problem would be in the manifest part because the java and xml works well...

The name of java files are:

1. PermissionActivity.java ==== shows permission to open location (works)
2. MainActivity.Java ==== shows the map (works)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.arcgismap">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".PermissionActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is that Whenever the Permission activity is done ... then 2nd activity which is the MainActivity that shows the map crashes before it shows the map..

Comment: Apparently forget  entry of `MainActivity` in manifest file .Also if its still crash add the crash logs and MainActivity code with question .

Comment: Thank youuu but how would i code it sir?

Comment: Well in order to solve your problem we need to see the crash report.. You should follow some code example from github if you are a starter ..

Answer (score 0):

Every activity you create, needs to be declared in Manifest as well, from your provided Manfiest i can see you haven't added your MainActivity, which causing crash.
Just add it in your application tag, above or below of PermissionActivity tag.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: @BigFatBelly add your crash logs, only then we can help you better.